# Creating Neutral network for line detection - is it possible?

Tags: image, neural-network, computer-vision, detection, lines

So I want to detect lines on grayscale images. I have a lot of data 9x9 matrices of pixel ints 1 to 256 and 1*4 matrices of ponnts coords X ,Y, X,Y We have 1 line per 9x9 image or non lines. So what structure should have my NN?

Comment: What would you need that NN for? Segmenting the lines should be an easy task for a Hough transformation... or do you need to track the segmented lines? Or do you want to distinguish lines from each other... so that the NN filters the lines you actually want from the ones you get?

Comment: There's no practical reason for the NN, so the only reason to do this is to play around with NNs.  In that case, the answer is whatever sort of NN you want to learn about or play with.  If there's more to the question than that, you'll have to tell us what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using the most common variety of neural networks, multillayer perceptrons, you'll have exactly as many input nodes as there are features.

The inputs may include transformed variables, in addition to the raw variables.  The number of hidden nodes is selected by you, but you should have enough to permit the neural network to adequately make the mapping.

The number of output nodes will be determined by the number of classes and the representation you choose.  Assuming two classes ("line", "not line" seems likely), you may use 1 output node, which indicates the estimated probability of one class (the probability of the remaining class being 1 minus the probability of the first class).

Answer (score 1):

Detecting simple lines on a grayscale image is a well known problem. A Hough transform would be suffice for the job. See http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_feature_detection.html?highlight=hough%20line#cv-houghlines for a function that implement finding lines using Hough Transform.

Can you try the above function and see if it works?

If it doesn't, please update your question with a sample image.

Comment: no - my point is not just to find lines (btw for that I am quite happy to use LSD line detector) I want to creat NN to find lines. And I will give to it teach base made with LSD I just do nnot get how to make NN structure for that.

Comment: You should update your original question with such details. Also provide a sample input.